How an Audio Signal is Modulated with FM?
An audio signal can have varying frequency and amplitude and both are the part of the information. But as per my knowledge , Frequency modulation is a technique where the frequency of the carrier wave is varied according to the amplitude or intensity of the modulating signal. So how does this work if under FM, if the carrier wave only has the in information about the intensity or the amplitude of the modulating signal as in FM , the carrier frequency is varied according to the intensity?
Someone had told me to use a Voltage Controllable Oscillator(VCO), but the question remain as VCOs also vary the frequency according to the intensity of the input signal.What if the input signal is also varying in frequency (ofcourse inside a range)?

Please don't cross-post like this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/715899/how-can-an-audio-signal-with-varying-frequency-be-modulated-using-fm That's rude; we just wasted time to write answers you've already gotten elsewhere! (same for the people on electronics.stackexchange.com)

Sorry, I'm new here and I thought that the "-1" means no one will answer my question... so I posted again here.

The audio signal is just varying amplitude over time. That's all there is to it – that's why you can just record the instantaneous voltage to say, a magnetic tape, or the instantaneous air pressure into the depth of a groove on a vinyl disk, and play it back.
Yes, you can also represent the same amplitude-over-time signal as a amplitude&phase-over-frequency signal – that's what the Fourier transform does. However, both sides, and especially the original amplitude-over-time, are the signal. The fact that you say

An audio signal can have varying frequency and amplitude and both are the part of the information

is a bit wrong – the complete information is the varying amplitude, which you can analyze to detect a varying frequency. (and it works the other way around, too).
So, you need to get your idea of what an audio signal is straight.
Anyway, you know that a microphone can just convert audio into voltage that varies over time.
Use that voltage to control a VCO. Done – that's FM.


What if the input signal is also varying in frequency (ofcourse inside
a range)?

Thinking of the audio input to an FM modulator as a frequency-varying signal is a complicating, confusing approach. As others have said, consider the audio voltage at a single moment in time - this is what goes into the modulator to determine the VCO's output frequency.
At a single moment in time, the audio voltage cannot be said to have any frequency information embedded...you need a continuous stretch of audio to determine its frequency components. That VCO only cares about instantaneous input voltage.
I'm just expressing Marcus' fine answer in a different way.

On FM, the bigger the change from the center frequency, the louder the sound. The faster the change from the center frequency, the higher in pitch.
